# Knockout data-bind in function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

Hello I tried something but I can't do that.

HTML

```
<div data-bind="dxTextBox: { value:my_var }"></div>
```

JS

```
var viewModel = {
   my_var: ko.observable(''),
   StartScan:function()
    {
        mytimer = setInterval(this.DataBind, 1000);
    },
   DataBind:function()
    {
        this.my_var('hello world');
    },}return viewModel;
```

İf I use this

```
<div data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'Start', onClick: DataBind}"></div>
```

It is OK. This returns me "hello world"

But If I use this

```
<div data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'Start', onClick: StartScan}"></div>
```

It returns me error like this ->
Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: this.my_var is not a function',

How can I solve this?

Comment: You need `mytimer = setInterval(this.DataBind.bind(this), 1000);`

Comment: @haim770 thanks it works. Can you write this as answer. So I mark this as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're passing a reference to a function to be later invoked by `setInterval` (or `setTimeout`), its context would be the global scope (`window` in this case). Hence `this.my_var` would obviously return `undefined`.

You need to explicitly `bind` it to the correct context (which is the `viewModel` that is holding it) using `.bind(this)`:

```
mytimer = setInterval(this.DataBind.bind(this), 1000);
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#With_setTimeout)